# Write a ETL in dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Hi I want to convert a transformation logic to dataflow for some analysis purpose. Below is the query i want to convert to a dataflow job.

```
select max(trans.TRANSACTIONS_ID) TRANSACTION_ID
, trans.ACCOUNT_ID ACCOUNT_ID
, max(dim.ACCOUNT_NAME) ACCOUNT_NAME 
, max(trans.DATE_ID) DATE_ID
, max(trans.CR_DR_INDICATOR) CR_DR_INDICATOR
, max(trans.TRANS_CODE) TRANS_CODE
, SUM(trans.AMOUNT) AMOUNT
, max(trans.BALANCE) BALANCE
, max(trans.TRANSACTION_TYPE) TRANSACTION_TYPE
, max(trans.BANK) BANK
, max(trans.ACCOUNT) ACCOUNT 
from `xxxxxxx.costing_uscase.TRANSACTIONS_MASTER_DATAFLOW_TEST`  trans, `xxxxxxxxxxx.costing_uscase.ACCOUNTS_MASTER_DATAFLOW_TEST_2` dim
where dim.ACCOUNT_ID = trans.ACCOUNT_ID
group by trans.ACCOUNT_ID;
```

I have used BigQueryTableIO.read to read from two table and used CoGroupBy but a bit confused on how to perform the aggregartion over a iterable table row.

Comment: Why do you want to read from BigQuery and do aggregation in Dataflow, rather than just doing it directly in BigQuery (which is a LOT faster)?

Comment: Yeah Graham agreed. Just for some analysis to be shared with client.